# Knp DoctrineBehaviors Tree getChildNodes

Tags: php, symfony, tree

I'm learning symfony and currently I'm looking into Knp DoctrineBehaviors Tree, and I'm confused a little bit, because in the trait: https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/blob/master/src/Knp/DoctrineBehaviors/Model/Tree/Node.php there is a $childNodes and getter getChildNodes() which make sense but getChildNodes always returns empty array for me and I agree with this because I don't set $childNodes any where so it will always return empty ArrayCollection. So my question is should my application look after this? Or I undestand that wrongly?

```
/**  
 * @var ArrayCollection $childNodes the children in the tree  
 */  
private $childNodes;  
...   
...   
...  

/**  
 * {@inheritdoc}  
 **/  
public function getChildNodes()  
{  
    return $this->childNodes = $this->childNodes ?: new ArrayCollection;  
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to set the child nodes. But the api for doing this are as bellow:

```
//To set $child as child node for a $parent entity
$child->setParentNode($parent);
//OR
$child->setChildOf($parent); 

$parent->isParentOf($child);  //return true
$child->isParentOf($parent);  //return false
```

Whenever you need to access getChildNodes() you need Build the tree first:

```
$root = $em->getRepository('Category')->getTree();

$root->getParent(); // null
$root->getChildNodes(); // ArrayCollection
$root[0][1]; // node or null
$root->isLeaf(); // boolean
$root->isRoot(); // boolean
```

The idea behind this tree implementation is that there is no relationship between parent and children (foreign key). All the relations are defined via a materialized path, a string stored in each node. So before build tree you can't access this `getParentNode()` and `getChildNodes()` functions.

Just for your thought: To get all child by parent_id you can define the following function in your repository

```
public function getChildrenByParentID($parentId)
{
    $parentPath = $this->find($parentId)->getRealMaterializedPath();

    return $this->getTree($parentPath)->getChildNodes();
}
```

**Updated:** You can use following function(define in your repository class) to read all root level nodes:

```
public function getRootLevelNodes()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');

    return $qb
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('t.materializedPath', '?1'))
        ->setParameter(1, '');
}
```

You can read more about [Doctrine ORM behaviors, or how to use traits efficiently](http://knplabs.com/blog/2012/03/30/knp-doctrine-orm-behaviors/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  

I did read the documentation but I think that I've understood it a little bit differently.  
  
Looking at it again tree always has to have a root where all nodes are coming from (I was thinking that I can have multiple root level nodes or I'm still on the wrong track?)

Comment: Yes you can have multiple root level nodes.